# Find the limit of a piecewise defined sequence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Given the sequence $$ d_n =\begin{cases} \frac{n}{1 + n^2}&  \text{if $1 ≤ n ≤ 900$}\\
    7        &   \text{if $n ≥ 901$}\end{cases}.$$
what is the limit?

I have been thinking that 7 is the limit...but not sure. and if we find the limit, L say, how do we prove that this piecewise sequence converges to L

Comment: In general, if the first part of a sequence does one thing, and the (infinite) rest does a second thing, you can completely ignore the first part. The first part of the sequence *never* affects its convergence properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $7$ is the limit. Given $\epsilon > 0$, choosing $N = 901$ will make $|d_n - 7| = |7 - 7| = 0 < \epsilon$ whenever $n \ge N$.